# How can I set up Nagios to monitor a webpage?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

How can I set up Nagios 3 to monitor a webpage? I would like to make sure it stays online. Also, if possible, I would like to have it check the page for a string to make sure the page is valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the plugin `check_http`. It has an option called `-s, --string=STRING String to expect in the content`.

Answer (score 3):

The Nagios [check_http plugin](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_http) does exactly what you're asking, and more.
Refer to the [Nagios Manual](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/toc.html) for information on how to set up Nagios and configure plugins if you are unsure how to do so.